# ImageMagick.NET only renders first page of a PDF file in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I'm trying to convert a PDF file into an image, however i only get the first page converted.
Heres what i have.
Code behind:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadPdf(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
            file.InputStream.CopyTo(target);
            byte[] data = target.ToArray();


            MagickReadSettings settings = new MagickReadSettings();
            settings.Density = new Density(300, 300);
            MemoryStream convertedFile = new MemoryStream();
            List<ImageModel> model = new List<ImageModel>();
            using (MagickImageCollection images = new MagickImageCollection())
            {
                images.Read(data,settings); // Read PDF file
                foreach (MagickImage image in images)
                {
                    ImageModel innerModle = new ImageModel();
                    image.Write(convertedFile, MagickFormat.Png);
                    byte[] data2 = convertedFile.ToArray();
                    innerModle.Image = data2;
                    model.Add(innerModle);                     
               }                 
            }                         
            return View(model);
        }
```

View model:

```
 public class ImageModel
    {
        public byte[] Image{ get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
@model List<DocumentViewerPoc.Models.ImageModel>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(item.Image);
    var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64);
    <img src="@imgSrc" />
}
```

I tried using  `convertedFile.Flush();`but that didn't do it for me. what am i missing here?
thanks :)

Comment: I imagine you will need to loop over each page of your PDF and convert them into separate images.

Comment: images.Read(data,settings); produces 2 objects (which is the same number of pages in the PDF im converting) but both have the same size. i don't know if that line reads the first page or it reads the entire document. Plus the foreach loop is supposed to loop through all the objects in images. so im confused actually :/

Comment: In your loop you have `image.Write(convertedFile, MagickFormat.Png);` - is this not writing the full PDF thus just 1 page. So each image is the same converted file. I see nothing where you write just a single pages data - i don't know the library, just what i see in your code.

Comment: convertedFile.Flush(); convertedFile.Dispose(); worked for me :)
thanks everyone :D

Answer (score 0):

change your code this below:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadPdf(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
        file.InputStream.CopyTo(target);
        byte[] data = target.ToArray();


        MagickReadSettings settings = new MagickReadSettings();
        settings.Density = new Density(300, 300);

        List<ImageModel> model = new List<ImageModel>();
        using (MagickImageCollection images = new MagickImageCollection())
        {
            images.Read(data,settings); // Read PDF file
            foreach (MagickImage image in images)
            {
                MemoryStream convertedFile = new MemoryStream();
                ImageModel innerModle = new ImageModel();
                image.Write(convertedFile, MagickFormat.Png);
                byte[] data2 = convertedFile.ToArray();
                innerModle.Image = data2;
                model.Add(innerModle);                     
           }                 
        }                         
        return View(model);
    }
```